# how to sum up specific cells of a column based on conditions from another column in R?

Tags: r, sum, dplyr

I have a small problem. I am working on a data frame. It is as follows:

```
df1
Duration    Intensity
NA             NA
10           0.1016
10           0.0254
NA             NA
NA             NA
10           0.0508
10           0.0508
10           0.1016
NA             NA
10           0.0254
```

I want to calculate the cumulative sum of “Intensity” for each events of 10 min “Duration”. Or in other words, I want to sum up the values of “Intensity” in between each ‘NA’ values in “Intensity” column. The output should look like this:

df2

```
Duration    Intensity   Intensity_sum
NA             NA   
10           0.1016 
10           0.0254        0.127
NA             NA   
NA             NA   
10           0.0508 
10           0.0508 
10           0.1016        0.2032
NA             NA   
10           0.0254        0.0254
```

I tried the following code:

```
library(dplyr)    
df2 <- as.data.frame(mutate(df1,Intensity_sum = with(df1,Duration==10,cumsum(Intensity))))
```

But I am only receiving TRUE or FALSE results, not the values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sum a variable by group?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660124/how-to-sum-a-variable-by-group)

Comment: @nrussell kind of, except that the OP would have to first construct the group ID, and also to "merge" on the aggregated sum to the final observation of each group.

Comment: @nrussell  Thanks, but my problem is not exactly the same as that one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by the run-length-id of logical vector (`!is.na(Duration)`), we assign (`:=`) the `sum` of 'Intensity' as 'Intensity_sum`and later replace the`duplicated` elements with 'NA'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, Intensity_sum := sum(Intensity), rleid(!is.na(Duration))]
df1[duplicated(Intensity_sum, fromLast=TRUE), Intensity_sum := NA]
df1
#     Duration Intensity Intensity_sum
# 1:       NA        NA            NA
# 2:       10    0.1016            NA
# 3:       10    0.0254        0.1270
# 4:       NA        NA            NA
# 5:       NA        NA            NA
# 6:       10    0.0508            NA
# 7:       10    0.0508            NA
# 8:       10    0.1016        0.2032
# 9:       NA        NA            NA
#10:       10    0.0254        0.0254
```

---

Or in a single line  we can group by `rleid` (as described above) and assign the new column by replicating `NA` along with the `sum` of 'Intensity'

```
setDT(df1)[, Intensity_sum := rep(c(NA,sum(Intensity)), c(.N-1, 1)), rleid(!is.na(Duration))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the fourth `data.table` method I suggest below, it is possible to achieved the desired result in base R. This method uses `ave` and `replace`

```
ave(df$Intensity, cumsum(is.na(df$Intensity)),
    FUN=function(x) replace(NA, (seq_along(x) == length(x) & length(x) > 1),
                            sum(x, na.rm=TRUE)))
 [1]     NA     NA 0.1270     NA     NA     NA     NA 0.2032     NA 0.0254
```

---

Here are some additional `data.table` options

```
df[, val := ifelse(is.na(shift(Intensity, type="lead")),
   sum(Intensity, na.rm=TRUE), NA), by=cumsum(is.na(Intensity))]
```

In this instance, grouping is performed using the `cumsum` function and placement of the sum is performed using `ifelse` that uses `shift` to check for NA boundaries.

This is a bit slower and will add 0 instead of NA if there is a single NA value with adjacent numeric values. The first argument of `ifelse` can be modified so this doesn't happen.

Second, a faster solution that using `c` and subsetting instead of `ifelse`. I added logic so that single rows of NA will receive and NA rather than 0.

```
df[, val2 := c(NA, sum(Intensity, na.rm=TRUE))[(seq_len(.N) == .N &.N > 1) + 1],
   by=cumsum(is.na(Intensity))]
```

Revising this method slightly to take advantage of a favorite manipulation of `NA`. we get the following.

```
df[, val3 := sum(Intensity, na.rm=TRUE) * NA^(seq_len(.N) != .N | .N == 1),
   by=cumsum(is.na(Intensity))]
```

This method takes advantage of the fact that `NA^x` where x != 0 returns NA, but `NA^0` returns 1 and `NA^FALSE` is equivalent to `NA^0`.

A fourth alternative is to use `replace`. This function replaces a vector with values at specified indices.

```
df[, val4 := replace(NA, (seq_len(.N) == .N & .N != 1),
                     sum(Intensity, na.rm=TRUE)),
   by=cumsum(is.na(Intensity))]
```

The results of the three methods are shown below.

```
df
    Duration Intensity   val3    val   val2   val4
 1:       NA        NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
 2:       10    0.1016     NA     NA     NA     NA
 3:       10    0.0254 0.1270 0.1270 0.1270 0.1270
 4:       NA        NA     NA 0.0000     NA     NA
 5:       NA        NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
 6:       10    0.0508     NA     NA     NA     NA
 7:       10    0.0508     NA     NA     NA     NA
 8:       10    0.1016 0.2032 0.2032 0.2032 0.2032
 9:       NA        NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
10:       10    0.0254 0.0254 0.0254 0.0254 0.0254
```